# Python: Capture the output of a REST API based DMS service post uploading document

Tags: python

I am trying to upload a file to a DMS via REST API. Each time I upload the file to DMS, an unique doc_id is generated which needs to be saved in DB.

I am trying out the following code for the first part i.e. upload.

```
def upload_sotr(filepath:str,file_name:str):
    upload_url = 'dms_url_path'
    f = open(os.path.join(filepath,file_name),'rb')
    files = {"file":(os.path.join(filepath,file_name),f)}
    resp = requests.post(url=url,files=files)
    if resp.status_code==201:
      print('Success!!')
      ##Want to get the doc_id as shown below and return the same
      return 'Success!!'
else:
    strg='Failure'
    return strg
```

However, I am not able to capture the doc_id string from `upload_url` post uploading the doc. Typically, doc_id is returned as

```
{
  doc_type: 'image',
  doc_id: 'AAD3456Q77'
}
```

As indicated in the code, what trick I should do post `print('Success!!')` so that I get the doc_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the trick!!

I should use

```
data = resp.json()
doc_id = data['doc_id''
return doc_id
```

So the complete code would be:

```
def upload_sotr(filepath:str,file_name:str):
  upload_url = 'dms_url_path'
  f = open(os.path.join(filepath,file_name),'rb')
  files = {"file":(os.path.join(filepath,file_name),f)}
  resp = requests.post(url=url,files=files)
  if resp.status_code==201:
    data = resp.json()
    doc_id = data['doc_id']
    return doc_id
 else:
    strg='Failure'
    return strg
```